# How to collect Azure Eventhub metrics that can't be exported to Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-eventhub, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

We are working with Azure Event Hub and want to build comprehensive monitoring plate, where we could collect some metrics that are not exportable via Diagnostics settings into Azure Monitor (Log Analytics Workspace). According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/monitor-event-hubs-reference#request-metrics) we can't export "Throttled Requests" or "Active Connections" for example. However we need such metrics to conduct advanced analysis and building control plate on our data platform.
How we can obtain such metrics in our storage ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the metrics using the Metrics API of the Azure Resource Manager. There are also SDKs available, e.g. for .NET.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list?tabs=HTTP